# Matches lines not starting by Date

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have some extracted text from pdf files, i'm looking for some keyWords to match job title, i tried to use many regex to get only the lines that not starting by a date ( any date format) but i have to get other line that start by any another number or words.

i hope find a brilient idea here. 
Best

I've tried this two regex to find *ingenieur* key word without any success :

```
    ((?m)^(?![0-9])\\s*\\b"+ sTofind +"\\b)
```

and this one also :

```
    ((?m)[^(?!(0-9))][\\s{2,4}]\\b"+ sTofind +"\\b.*)
```

the text test that i use is this one (the > Character is not part of text) :

```
etudiant -: ingenieur etudes et developpement
http://www.doyoubuzz.com/profilen
experiences  
ingenieur
2018-2014      ingenieur 
331    ingenieur


29 rue de la terrasse    Ingenieur Centrale Lyon / Supélec 
93160 NOISY LE GRAND    ingenieur  
09 66 11 10 93       Expertise en instrumentation industrielle, 
06 44 25 90 09     automatisation ingenieur & marketing opérationnel 
email.email@wanadoo.fr   Bilingue anglais  ingenieur
```

i expect to find the highlighted text  :

```
etudiant -: <i>ingenieur etudes et developpement</i>
http://www.doyoubuzz.com/profilen
<i>experiences</i>
<i>ingenieur</i>
2018-2014      ingenieur 
331    <i>ingenieur</i>


29 rue de la terrasse    <i>Ingenieur Centrale Lyon / Supélec </i>
93160 NOISY LE GRAND    <i>ingenieur</i>  
09 66 11 10 93       Expertise en instrumentation industrielle, 
06 44 25 90 09     automatisation <i>ingenieur & marketing opérationnel </i>
email.email@wanadoo.fr   Bilingue anglais  <i>ingenieur</i>
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?mi)^((?!>[0-9]+-[0-9]+).*?)(\bingenieur\b.*)` https://regex101.com/r/CKAbT1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

```
(?mi)^((?![0-9]+-[0-9]+).*?)(\bingenieur\b.*)
```

About the pattern

- `(?mi)` Multiline and case insensitive flag
- `^` Start of the string
- `(` Capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is immediatiately on the right is not

    - `[0-9]+-[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits, a hyphen and 1+ digits
  - )`.*?` Close negative lookahead and match any character except a newline non greedy
- `)` Close capturing group
- `(\bingenieur\b.*)` Capturing group that matches ingenieur between word boundaries till the end of the string

You could enable the multiline and case insensitive flag using in the code, for example:

```
String sTofind = "ingenieur";
String regex = "^((?!>[0-9]+-[0-9]+).*?)(\\b"+ sTofind + "\\b.*)";
String string = "...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xxc5KS/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/a7v8kf)

Then you can also replace ingenieur with `experiences` if you also want to highlight that.

And replace with the 2 capturing groups where you could highlight the second group:

`$1<i>$2</i>`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, the > character is not part of the text, i think your solution is the best until now so i can get the second group 2 to get the matching from the key word. Thanks you for your answer, i will wait for other answer , if there is no more best answer i will check yours as the best one.

Comment: If the `>` is not part of the text, you could just omit it from the pattern `String regex = "^((?![0-9]+-[0-9]+).*?)(\\b"+ sTofind + "\\b.*)";`

Comment: yes , this what i did , and its working i thinks, your response is the best . i will mark it as answered. Thank you very much